# I2C общение средствами STM32 LL

Tags: stm32

Всем привет!

Подскажите как правильно отправить пару байт в i2c без HAL, но с LL?
Пробую так, но бит TXIS не выставляется. Что делаю не так то?

```
// Send data
void i2c_WriteData(uint8_t* buffer, size_t buff_size) {
#ifdef USE_HAL_DRIVER
    HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&I2C_PORT, I2C_ADDR, 0x40, 1, buffer, buff_size, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
#else
    if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_BUSY(I2C_PORT)) return;
    LL_I2C_ClearFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT);
    LL_I2C_ClearFlag_TXE(I2C_PORT);
    LL_I2C_HandleTransfer(I2C_PORT,I2C_ADDR,LL_I2C_ADDRSLAVE_7BIT,buff_size,LL_I2C_MODE_SOFTEND,LL_I2C_GENERATE_START_WRITE);
    if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT)) {
error:
        LL_I2C_ClearFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT);
        LL_I2C_GenerateStopCondition(I2C_PORT);
        return;
    }
    do {
        while (1) {
            if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXIS(I2C_PORT)) break;
            if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT)) goto error;
        }
        LL_I2C_TransmitData8(I2C_PORT, *buffer++);
    } while(--buff_size>0);
    while (!LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TC(I2C_PORT)) {}
    LL_I2C_GenerateStopCondition(I2C_PORT);
#endif
}
```

в результате зацикливается на проверке TXIS, а ожидалось, что там будет бит свободности регистра для записи в него.

В результате работает это:

```
#define I2C_PORT I2C1

bool i2c_WriteReg(uint8_t addr, uint8_t reg, const uint8_t *data, size_t len, uint16_t to)
{
    bool res = true;
    if (!LL_I2C_IsEnabled(I2C_PORT))
        LL_I2C_Enable(I2C_PORT);
    if ((len<=0) || LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_BUSY(I2C_PORT))
    {
        res = false; //шина кем-то занята. Работать нельзя. Другой мастер?
    }
    else
    {
        uint32_t timeout = getSysticks();
        bool started = false;
        while (len>0) {
            uint8_t chunk_remain = ((len >= 0xFF) ? 0xFF : (len+1));        // разбиваем общую длину на отрезки по 255 байт.
            LL_I2C_ClearFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT);
            if (!started) {                                                 // если это первый отрезок
                //Нужно отправить Start и адрес устройства в i2c
                LL_I2C_HandleTransfer(I2C_PORT, addr, LL_I2C_ADDRSLAVE_7BIT, chunk_remain, (len>=0xFF)?LL_I2C_MODE_RELOAD:LL_I2C_MODE_AUTOEND, LL_I2C_GENERATE_START_WRITE);
                while (1) {
                    if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT)) goto error;  //Слейв не подтвердил что он есть на шине, надо прекратить отправку - некому слать.
                    if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXE(I2C_PORT))  break;  //Байт адреса вытолкнут в шину и можно писать своё

                    if (getSysticks()-timeout>=to) {
                        goto error;
                    }
                }
                LL_I2C_ClearFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT);
                LL_I2C_TransmitData8(I2C_PORT, reg);                        //адрес регистра
                started = true;                                             //помечаем что первый пройден
                chunk_remain--;                                             //уменьшаем общую длину на 1, т.к. только что один отправили
            } else
                //Настройка на последующий кусок данных после предыдущих 255 байт, вроде как start уже отправлять не надо
                LL_I2C_HandleTransfer(I2C_PORT, addr, LL_I2C_ADDRSLAVE_7BIT, chunk_remain, (len>=0xFF)?LL_I2C_MODE_RELOAD:LL_I2C_MODE_AUTOEND, LL_I2C_GENERATE_NOSTARTSTOP);
            while (chunk_remain>0) {                                        //Пока кусок не нулевой отправляесм его
                //Ждём отправки предыдущего байта
                while (1) {
                    if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT)) goto error;
                    if (LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TXE(I2C_PORT))  break;  //Байт адреса вытолкнут в шину и можно писать новый

                    if (getSysticks()-timeout>=to) {
                        goto error;
                    }
                }
                LL_I2C_ClearFlag_NACK(I2C_PORT);
                LL_I2C_TransmitData8(I2C_PORT, *data++);
                chunk_remain--;
                len--;
            }
            if (len>0)                                             //если после отправки куска общая длина ещё имеет место быть,
                while (!LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_TCR(I2C_PORT)) {};     //то логично что отправка многокусковая и нажо дождаться фактического завершения куска. ХЗ - так написано в мануале.
        }
        //Ждём окончания отправки СТОП
        while (!LL_I2C_IsActiveFlag_STOP(I2C_PORT)) {}
error:
        LL_I2C_ClearFlag_STOP(I2C_PORT);
    }
    LL_I2C_Disable(I2C_PORT);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё оказалось банально. в L0 серии в режиме мастера не нужно слать адрес в шину самостоятельно, i2c это делает сам. Для этого в LL есть макрос `LL_I2C_HandleTransfer()`
внутри которого так же есть указание на длину будущей отправки. Для классического применения i2c - Memory Write нужно отправить `Start ADDR WriteBit OFFSET DATA-n Stop`, где OFFSET обывчно байт или два смещения внутри Memory, а DATA-n данные длиною n для записи по смещению. Так вот. Передав в `LL_I2C_HandleTransfer()` длину будущей отправки нужно вычислить её исходя из длины смещения (1 или 2 байта) и длины всех данных (отдельный случай если результат более 255). Таким образом i2c сформирует Start отправит адрес и бит записи или чтения (см. последний флаг макроса). Далее нужно дождаться появления флага TXE (или TXIE в случае AUTO) и отправлять последовательно байты начиная со смещения и данные. Перед каждой отправкой дожидаясь наличия бита TXE. По окончании, после последнего байта данных, дождаться бита TC (или TCR) и завершить отправку отправив STOP или это можно сделать автоматически передав нужный флаг в `LL_I2C_HandleTransfer()`.

Comment: **Spider**, можете выложить финальный код вашей функции i2c_WriteData() ?
Я не совсем понял, что именно вы изменили в итоге. Ковыряю камень STM32L011, там во флешку 16K помещается только код, сгенерированный для LL.

Comment: Обновил начальный пост

Comment: @Urik_EEE подскажите пожайлуста, не получается увидеть stlink новую микросхему у меня stm32L152RBT6, 64 ног, собираю на макетке TQFP32-100. новокупленные stlink должен видеть? Чаще проблема с питанием, тактированием, или её шить надо?

Comment: Всё должно быть "из коробки" ничего настраивать или "шить" не нужно. Всё работает и так.